# RA layer request failed while git-svn fetch

Tags: git-svn

I use git svn to sync with the subversion repos:

```
$ mkdir prj && cd prj
$ git svn init http://url/to/repos/branches/experimental
$ git svn fetch
```

and got the error message:

```
RA layer request failed: OPTIONS of 'http://url/to/repos/branches/experimental':
Could not read status line: connection was closed by proxy server 
(http://url/to/repos) at /usr/bin/git-svn line 1352
```

Why and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue when accessing a SVN repo **through a proxy**.

The solution for me was to edit `~/.subversion/servers` and add the needed proxy to the `[globals]` section. Uncomment the relevant lines (`http-proxy-host`, `http-proxy-port`, optionally `http-proxy-username` and `http-proxy-password`) and enter the needed information there.

This is needed because `git svn` uses the settings stored in `~/.subversion/servers` to access SVN repositories.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like this is a timeout issue on the server. Here's [one bug report](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/sourceforge/ticket/1576) (I can't access the ticket it's a duplicate of, unfortunately). It's happening a lot to me, but if I just try the command again, it gets a little farther before timing out again. Eventually, I'll have the whole repository, and won't have to do this again, I hope.

Answer (score 2):

I witnessed the similar

> Could not read response body: connection was closed by server

I was able to resolve it by setting **Timeout** to 6000 in the Apache config.